# Link up one cell to another cell in the same worksheet Excel

Tags: vba, excel

What I want to achieve is that when I click on a cell consisting text, I want the view to be transafered to the place the cell is linked/connected.

For instance, let us say I have 50 columns. It is time consuming if I was to move to the right to column number 48,35 or 40. Therefor I want for instance a cell or maybe a button that navigates me to the corresponding columns.

I have tried searching, but maybe the function is named something else.. Anyway, I hope someone can give me a clue of how I can make this happen, or where the information is located.

Here are two pictures describe what I am trying to achieve. 
[image: After I press this button]

[image: The result]

Comment: You could always click the 'Trace Precedents' button and double click on the line it draws - it will take you between the two cells.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a really a link that you are talking about, but if you affect this code to a button, it should cover your needs :

```
Sub test_navi()

    Dim ColNb As Integer

    ColNb = InputBox("Type the number of the column you want to go to :", "Navigation", "38")
    If ColNb > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, ColNb).Select
    Else
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is good, but I am want the to connect the button to the location, without needing to input which place is shall move too. I want the user to click the button and be directed to the correct place without any text input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Cell A1` contains the number by which you want columns to be moved, you can use:

```
col = CLng(Range("A1").Value)
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = col
```

Answer (score 0):

following the "cell" idea , you could use the worksheet `Worksheet_Change` event

so that you type the wanted column index in cell "A1" (but it can be whatever cell you like) and have it "automagically" select the chosen column

place the following code in the worksheet code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim val As Long
    Dim strng As String
    Dim mixed As Boolean

    If Target.Address(False, False) = "A1" Then '<~~ just change "A1" with whatever cell address you want to type column index in
        If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        GetValAndNumber Target, val, strng, mixed '"interpret" the value input in cell A1

        On Error Resume Next 'prevent possible invalid inputs could error subsequent 'Range' methods calls
        If mixed Then
            Range(Target.Value).Select
        Else
            Cells(1, Target.Value).Select
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub


Sub GetValAndNumber(cell As Range, valLng As Long, strng As String, mixed As Boolean)
    Dim valStrng As String, char As String
    Dim i As Long

    With cell
        For i = 1 To Len(.Value2)
            char = Mid(.Value2, i, 1)
            If char Like "[0-9]" Then
                valStrng = valStrng & char
                If strng <> "" Then Exit For
            Else
                strng = strng & char
                If valStrng <> "" Then Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    mixed = strng <> "" And valStrng <> ""
    If strng <> "" Then
        mixed = valStrng <> ""
        If mixed Then valLng = CLng(valStrng)
    Else
        If valStrng <> "" Then valLng = CLng(valStrng)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these two bits of code - works if your cell only has a single precedent.

```
Public Sub FindPrecedent()

    Dim StartCell As Range
    Set StartCell = ActiveCell
    StartCell.ShowPrecedents
    StartCell.NavigateArrow TowardPrecedent:=True, ArrowNumber:=1, LinkNumber:=1
    StartCell.Parent.ClearArrows

End Sub

Public Sub FindDependent()

    Dim StartCell As Range
    Set StartCell = ActiveCell
    StartCell.ShowDependents
    StartCell.NavigateArrow TowardPrecedent:=False, ArrowNumber:=1, LinkNumber:=1
    StartCell.Parent.ClearArrows

End Sub
```